# Multiple case statements in H2 where clause

Tags: prepared-statement, h2

I'm new to H2. Does the H2 database allow to use of multiple case statements within a where clause? The H2 documentation only mentions a single case statement in the [example](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#case_when). Because when I try using multiple case statements, the connection.preparedStatement(query) returns a NullPointer. I'm confident that the connection is created successfully because the other tests run perfectly.

The following is the query I use as the java prepared statement (with multiple case statements)

```
SELECT * FROM AUDIT_RECORDS WHERE ID = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN ID ELSE ? END AND STATUS = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN STATUS ELSE ? END
```

When I use a single case statement, the flow works. When I use multiple cases, it gives the NullPointer.

Is there a way to configure H2 to see the inner logs so I can analyze and pinpoint the issue? I assume that there might be a problem with the interpretation of the prepared statement to the driver. I also run this same query in a separate H2 server (not an embedded one) and it worked fine.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a direct answer, but `CASE` expressions are not the most appropriate thing here.  I would use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM AUDIT_RECORDS
WHERE ID = COALESCE(?, ID) AND STATUS = COALESCE(?, STATUS);
```

This approach lets you just bind each `?` placeholder value once.

Comment: even if this is not a direct answer, this helped me to achieve my goal with a much simpler query. But I still wonder why it throws a null pointer when I add multiple case statements in the where caluse in H2. Thanks for your answer. But the above issue is still valid.